# Failure I can't connect from bigquery to cloud sql postgres

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

Failure I can't connect from bigquery to cloud sql postgres
Good morning everyone, I wanted to bother you with the following problem:
I have tried to make an external connection from bigquery, to cloud sql, I entered the connection credentials but I always get the error.
"Invalid table-valued function EXTERNAL_QUERY Connect to PostgreSQL server failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request. at [1:15]"
The Cloud Sql instance, has not enabled the public ip for security reasons (and there is no chance to enable it).
Enable the option :
"Enable private route
Allow other Google Cloud services, such as BigQuery, to access the data and perform queries through a private IP" and it didn't work either.
both cloud sql and BQ are in the same project.

What solution could you give me?

Comment: Did you configure a private access? https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-private-ip#private_services_access

Comment: Yes sir, i configure the private access

Comment: Check that the service account that creates the external connection has the BigQuery Connection Service Agent permission?